sys.path.insert(0, '..') not working in py file while working in juyter notebook
I have a py file saved in a subfolder, and it need to import a module in main folder which is one level up. I am using sys.path.insert(0, '..').
Then it works when the code is executed in cell in jupyter notebook. However, it doesn't work when code is written in py file. any reason?
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '..')

from python_environment_check import check_packages

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_environment_check'



how do you run your .py file?

Are you sure you running jupyter notebook and this script from same folders? You could check this by print(os.getcwd())

Thanks, after using print(os.getcwd()), it show it is main folder, not current working folder.
